# Disable site collection feature selectively at web level

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

If there is a feature with scope as site collection has been activated then is it possible to deactivate it at web level for a particular child web level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. I would recommend that you create Web-scoped feature which reverses the effects of the site-scoped one, and then activates that on selected webs.

Comment: Thanks Rikard. I agree with you. But I was wondering if there was any other neat way, may be using Power Shell Scripting.

Comment: Not that I know of. What does your site-scoped feature do? Maybe I can help you better if you describe what you want to accomplish.

Comment: there is a site collection which has two types of spweb - regular and concept. The information of these spwebs is stored in a list of the site collection root web with spweb name, url and type (regular or concept). The site scoped feature to be activated needs to target regular spwebs only. 
both regular and concept spwebs are provisioned using the same site templates.

Comment: All right, but what happens when you activate the site scoped feature? What does it do to the concept webs that you want undone?

Comment: WebPart is available in WebPart gallery once feature is installed and activated. The requirement is to have this WebPart to be available only for the Project type spweb and users in the concept type spweb should not be able to add the WebPart to their pages.

Comment: There is actually a really nice way in SP2010 to conditionally decide which webparts to be available at which webs. Take a look at this blogpost by Chris O'Brien: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012_01_01_archive.html